# Most concise way to convert a Set<T> to a List<T>

Tags: java, list, collections, set, java-6

For example, I am currently doing this:

```
Set<String> setOfTopicAuthors = ....

List<String> list = Arrays.asList( 
    setOfTopicAuthors.toArray( new String[0] ) );
```

Can you beat this ?

Comment: Use `java.util.Collection`: O(0)

Comment: @Carl, I have to submit the Set into a 3rd party interface which requires a List.  @Tim I wish I could change the 3rd party interface to use Collection.

Comment: I see; barring any strange constraints, I'd go with Roger's answer.  Though, unless you actually use the List again, I'd skip assigning it to anything (i.e., use foo.api(new ArrayList<String>(listOfTopicAuthors)) instead of foo.api(list)).

Comment: @JacquesRenéMesrine:
First line of code in question is misleading:
Expected: `Set<String> setOfTopicAuthors = ....`
Actual: `Set<String> listOfTopicAuthors = ....`

Comment: Or an alternate way to do the same could be [`List<String> list = Arrays.asList(setOfTopicAuthors.toArray(String[]::new))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51545469/1746118), detailed in the linked answer.

Comment: Java 8 and Java 10 solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32179585/1216775

Answer (score 453, accepted):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(listOfTopicAuthors);
```

Comment: ... and thereby radically defying the Java code conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html ! :) :)

Comment: after this when I tried to access list element it giving me error, " java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String" ..don;t know why..it's simple list.get(int) that's it ...any suggestion ?

Comment: I believe in Java 7 and above you can omit the type parameter to `ArrayList` yielding:


    ```List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(listOfTopicAuthors);```


Most concise without using an external library?

Comment: It will throw NullPointerException in case `listOfTopicAuthors` is null.

Answer (score 94):

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(listOfTopicAuthors);
```

Comment: for answering in the same minute as accepted answer and not getting the cred. +1

Comment: @Adamski I end up with a list who's index begins at 1 instead of 0, any remedy?

Comment: @Jack: That definitely won't be the case.  From the Javadoc from java.util.List: "Lists (like Java arrays) are zero based."

Comment: @Adamski Thanks for the response. I know lists should be and are zero based which is why this is so strange to me. After converting my set to a list I can't perform any iterative operation on it foreach, sort, etc. I get a NullPointerException, however when I expect my list none of the elements are null, and the only weird I notice is that the index starts at 1. However, if I just create a normal list the index starts at 0. Weird?

Comment: @Jack: That sounds very weird.  If you post your code as a separate question I'm sure someone will be able to help you out.

Answer (score 25):

Considering that we have `Set<String> stringSet` we can use following:

### Plain Java

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>(stringSet);
```

### Guava

```
List<String> strList = Lists.newArrayList(stringSet);
```

### Apache Commons

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
CollectionUtils.addAll(strList, stringSet);
```

### Java 10 (Unmodifiable List)

```
List<String> strList = List.copyOf(stringSet);
List<String> strList = stringSet.stream().collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
```

### Java 8 (Modifiable Lists)

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
List<String> stringList1 = stringSet.stream().collect(toList());
```

As per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) for the method `toList()`

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or
> thread-safety of the List returned; if more control over the returned
> List is required, use toCollection(Supplier).

So if we need a specific implementation e.g. `ArrayList` we can get it this way:

```
List<String> stringList2 = stringSet.stream().
                              collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

### Java 8 (Unmodifiable Lists)

We can make use of `Collections::unmodifiableList` method and wrap the list returned in previous examples. We can also write our own custom method as:

```
class ImmutableCollector {
    public static <T> Collector<T, List<T>, List<T>> toImmutableList(Supplier<List<T>> supplier) {
            return Collector.of( supplier, List::add, (left, right) -> {
                        left.addAll(right);
                        return left;
                    }, Collections::unmodifiableList);
        }
}
```

And then use it as:

```
List<String> stringList3 = stringSet.stream()
             .collect(ImmutableCollector.toImmutableList(ArrayList::new));
```

Another possibility is to make use of `collectingAndThen` method which allows some final transformation to be done before returning result:

```
    List<String> stringList4 = stringSet.stream().collect(collectingAndThen(
      toCollection(ArrayList::new),Collections::unmodifiableList));
```

---

One **point to note** is that the method `Collections::unmodifiableList` returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list, as per [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-). An unmodifiable view collection is a collection that is unmodifiable and is also a view onto a backing collection. Note that changes to the backing collection might still be possible, and if they occur, they are visible through the unmodifiable view. But the collector method `Collectors.unmodifiableList` returns truly immutable list in **Java 10**.

Comment: I used this to convert a `Set<Double>` to a `List<Double`, where the set came from a `LinkedHashMap`'s `.keySet()` method. Eclipse told me that there was a type mismatch, and that I could not convert from `Object` to `List<Double>`. Could you tell me why this may have happened? I got around it by casting, but I was wondering why it happens.

Comment: Yes, since Java Developers should be using more and more Java 8 features, this answer is better than the above 2 answers.

Answer (score 14):

Try this for [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html):

```
Set<String> listOfTopicAuthors = .....
List<String> setList = new ArrayList<String>(listOfTopicAuthors);
```

Try this for [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html):

```
Map<String, String> listOfTopicAuthors = .....
// List of values:
List<String> mapValueList = new ArrayList<String>(listOfTopicAuthors.values());
// List of keys:
List<String> mapKeyList = new ArrayList<String>(listOfTopicAuthors.KeySet());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Guava, you statically import `newArrayList` method from [Lists](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28java.lang.Iterable%29) class:

```
List<String> l = newArrayList(setOfAuthors);
```

Answer (score 0):

not really sure what you're doing exactly via the context of your code but...

why make the `listOfTopicAuthors` variable at all?

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList((....).toArray( new String[0] ) );
```

the "...." represents however your set came into play, whether it's new or came from another location.