# The easiest way to transform collection to array?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, transformation

Suppose we have a `Collection<Foo>`. What is the best (shortest in LoC in current context) way to transform it to `Foo[]`? Any *well-known* libraries are allowed.

UPD: (one more case in this section; leave comments if you think it's worth to create another thread for it): What about transforming `Collection<Foo>` to `Bar[]` where `Bar` has constructor with 1 parameter of type `Foo` i.e. `public Bar(Foo foo){ ... }` ?

Comment: [Made this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51545469/1746118) with an alternate API introduced in JDK-11 to perform the same operation with similar performance and the explanation along with it. Plus the syntax matches the existing `Stream.toArray` API from the JDK.

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Where `x` is the collection:

```
Foo[] foos = x.toArray(new Foo[x.size()]);
```

Comment: **simpler** (easier) but not best(memory): `x.toArray(new Foo[0])`  ---  **documentation**: no time to read...

Comment: @Carlos actually, it uses better memory than `(new Foo[0])`. As per the Collection.toArray documentation, ` @param a the array into which the elements of this collection are to be stored, if it is big enough` which means it will store them directly in that new array. If you give it a size 0 array, it will make a new array, meaning you have a small array and a large array being made when such is unnecessary.

Comment: @glowcoder - but this can be minimized if you define a empty array once as a static constant. It's just a hint for `toArray` to create a target array of the correct type. And in this case, honestly, I wouldn't care about one extra single empty array in my application. That's far below noise level.

Comment: @glowcoder - that's exactly why I (*tried to*) wrote that using `new Foo[0]` is simpler "but not best (memory)"... that is, I meant that my solution is easier but not best (that's the reason I used `:` ).

Comment: Note that this code is not threadsafe, even if you're using a synchronized collection.  It'll behave itself in most situations, but if an item is deleted between the call to x.size() and x.toArray(), the resulting array will contain an extra null element at the end.  The `new Foo[0]` variant proposed by Carlos does not suffer this problem.

Comment: @Jules: For what it's worth it is also not suitable for some "funny" collections like `WeakHashMap`.

Comment: @Jules - where in the documentation do you see that the `new Foo[0]` version is thread safe? I'm sure that internally the implementation will still first check the size of the list, then create a new array if required, then fill it. Since the documentation does not explicitly mention thread safety, I'm pretty sure you should not rely on it being so. (edit: fix wording).

Comment: @JandeVos - Yes, it does do exactly what you say, but it does *inside a synchronized method* (if using a synchronized collection, as I described in my comment) and hence atomically without possibility of the collection being modified while that happens.  This is quite obvious from the documentation for `synchronizedList` that states: "Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) list backed by the specified list."  This implies that *all individual operations provided by the object are thread safe*, including the one described.  doublep's suggestion, however, uses 2 operations separately, which isn't.

Comment: Surprisingly `new Foo[0]` is the most performant. It's important to realize that the JVM, or a compiler, is free to do as it pleases so long as the semantics of code are preserved. In this case it can optimize this method best when a dynamic size is *not* provided. [Source](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/)

Answer (score 44):

Alternative solution to the updated question using Java 8:

```
Bar[] result = foos.stream()
    .map(x -> new Bar(x))
    .toArray(size -> new Bar[size]);
```

Comment: This can be shortened to

`Bar[] result = foos.stream().map(Bar::new).toArray(Bar[]::new);`

Comment: Syntax wise I'd much prefer the accepted answer. I wish people can all switch to Python.

Comment: @EricChen Switch to Python - an interpreted and dynamically typed language from  Java - 'compiled and statically typed language' because of coding syntax and number lines differ? Not a good idea.

Answer (score 11):

If you use it more than once or in a loop, you could define a constant

```
public static final Foo[] FOO = new Foo[]{};
```

and do the conversion it like

```
Foo[] foos = fooCollection.toArray(FOO);
```

The `toArray` method will take the empty array to determine the correct type of the target array and create a new array for you.

---

Here's my proposal for the update:

```
Collection<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
Collection<Bar> temp = new ArrayList<Bar>();
for (Foo foo:foos) 
    temp.add(new Bar(foo));
Bar[] bars = temp.toArray(new Bar[]{});
```

Comment: ups, `const` is not Java! `public static final Foo[] FOO = {}`

Comment: why would it be public?

Comment: @Zoltán - why not? It's immutable, so doesn't present a safety issue.  It's a little bit of clutter, but could be useful in other code, so is generally harmless.  Maybe even create a central class with all of these constants, and then use `import static` to get at them.

Comment: @Jules the reference to the array is immutable, but the contents of it aren't. Anyone outside the class can replace the elements of the array freely. And on the other hand, as a rule of thumb, I believe all fields should be made private until they are needed outside the class.

Comment: Being zero length, there are no contents that can be changed

Answer (score 9):

With JDK/11, an alternate way of converting a `Collection<Foo>` to an `Foo[]` could be to make use of [**`Collection.toArray(IntFunction<T[]> generator)`**](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8060192) as:

```
Foo[] foos = fooCollection.toArray(new Foo[0]); // before JDK 11
Foo[] updatedFoos = fooCollection.toArray(Foo[]::new); // after JDK 11
```

---

As explained by *[@Stuart on the mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2018-June/053825.html)*(emphasis mine), the performance of this should essentially be the same as that of the existing **`Collection.toArray(new T[0])`** --

> The upshot is that implementations that use `Arrays.copyOf(`) are the
>   fastest,  probably because *it's an intrinsic*.
>
> It can avoid zero-filling the freshly allocated array because it knows the 
>   entire array contents will be overwritten.  This is true regardless of what
>   the public API looks like.

The implementation of the API within the JDK reads:

```
default <T> T[] toArray(IntFunction<T[]> generator) {
    return toArray(generator.apply(0));
}
```

> The default  implementation calls `generator.apply(0)` to get a zero-length array
>   and then  simply calls `toArray(T[])`. This goes through the `Arrays.copyOf()` 
>   fast path, so it's essentially the same speed as **`toArray(new T[0])`**.

---

***Note***:- Just that the API use shall be guided along with a *backward incompatibility* when used for code with `null` values e.g. **`toArray(null)`** since these calls would now be ambiguous because of existing `toArray(T[] a)` and would fail to compile.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Guava in your project you can use [`Iterables::toArray`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#toArray-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Class-).

```
Foo[] foos = Iterables.toArray(x, Foo.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the final solution for the case in update section (with the help of Google Collections):

```
Collections2.transform (fooCollection, new Function<Foo, Bar>() {
    public Bar apply (Foo foo) {
        return new Bar (foo);
    }
}).toArray (new Bar[fooCollection.size()]);
```

But, the key approach here was mentioned in [the doublep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293946/the-easiest-way-to-transform-collection-to-array/3293970#3293970) (I forgot for `toArray` method).

Comment: See my comment on doublep's answer about thread safety, which also applies to this solution.  `new Bar[0]` avoids the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For the original see [doublep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293946/the-easiest-way-to-transform-collection-to-array/3293970#3293970) answer:

```
Foo[] a = x.toArray(new Foo[x.size()]);
```

As for the update:

```
int i = 0;
Bar[] bars = new Bar[fooCollection.size()];
for( Foo foo : fooCollection ) { // where fooCollection is Collection<Foo>
    bars[i++] = new Bar(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually in modern Java, the version without setting the explicit size is faster. See this SO answer:

[.toArray(new MyClass[0]) or .toArray(new MyClass[myList.size()])?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093/toarraynew-myclass0-or-toarraynew-myclassmylist-size)

This is backed up by independent research and the team at IntelliJ.

That is, this is the fastest approach today:

```
Foo[] foos = x.toArray(new Foo[0])
```

Or, even better, with a bit of safety:

```
Foo[] foos = x == null ? null : x.toArray(new Foo[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Foo[] foos = x.toArray(new Foo[0]);

Answer (score -1):

For example, you have collection ArrayList with elements Student class:

```
List stuList = new ArrayList();
Student s1 = new Student("Raju");
Student s2 = new Student("Harish");
stuList.add(s1);
stuList.add(s2);
//now you can convert this collection stuList to Array like this
Object[] stuArr = stuList.toArray();           // <----- toArray() function will convert collection to array
```