# Add values to an array in loop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

In my program, I am trying to add values to an array while it is looping. Before it is put in the array, it has to fulfill the if statement. I need to be able to add as many values as needed based on the input. I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
for(int a=0; a<= subset1white.length-1;a++){
  String w = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(subset1white[a]) + 2);
  String x = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(subset1white[a]) - 2);
  String y = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(subset1white[a]) + 10);
  String z = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(subset1white[a]) - 10);
  String[] arithmetic = {w, x, y, z};
     for(int b=0; b<= arithmetic.length-1; b++){
        if(arithmetic[b] == subset1black[a]){

        }
     }

  }
```

If the `if` loop returns true, I need the `subset1black[a]` value to be put in an array called  `result`. I know how to declare arrays but I do not know how to declare an array where the length can be changed(new values added).

Comment: Why don't you use the `ArrayList`? It's like an array that can grow dynamically when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ArrayList<Integer>` which can grow dynamically as needed (as suggested by [Bhesh Gurung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432039/add-values-to-an-array-in-loop#comment34112647_22432039)):

```
// Declare
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Add to end of the list
result.add(subset1black[a]);
```

See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for more information or if you want to add the elements to the list in a different way.

If you really need a primitive array, you can convert the `List`. See this [related Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293946/the-easiest-way-to-transform-collection-to-array).

Answer (score 0):

There are no variable size primitive arrays in Java, so the closest to such a data structure is the `ArrayList` class, which internally is an array of objects, resized when necessary. It helps to initialize the `ArrayList` to the anticipated size (or a bit more), to avoid resizing, but this optimization is not necessary.

For the code in question, an implementation of the above could be:

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(subset1white.length);

for (int a=0; a<subset1white.length; a++) {

  String w = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(subset1white[a]) + 2);
  String x = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(subset1white[a]) - 2);
  String y = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(subset1white[a]) + 10);
  String z = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(subset1white[a]) - 10);

  String[] arithmetic = {w, x, y, z};

  for (int b=0; b<= arithmetic.length-1; b++) {
    if (arithmetic[b] == subset1black[a]) {
      result.add(new Integer(subset1black[a]));
    }
  }    
}
```

It is not necessary to initialize an `Integer` object to add to the `ArrayList`, since `Java` does that automatically (via "autoboxing"), but doing so makes the code a bit cleaner.