# Converting List of objects to an Array of Strings

Tags: java

In my main class, I have: `List<Person> allPeople = new ArrayList<>();`

Then in the class I have a method which returns a String array of all the `Id` of people (Person has an accessor method `getId()` ).

What is the prettiest way to convert the list to an array with just the Ids as String?

This is my current solution:

```
public String[] getAllId() {

    Object[] allPeopleArray = allPeople.toArray();
    String allId[] = new String[allPeople.size()];              

    for(int i=0; i<=allPeople.size()-1; i++){
        allId[i] = ((Person)allPeopleArray [i]).getId();                    
    }

    return allId;
}
```

Above works, but is there a 'better' way to do this?

Comment: Do you need to return `String[]` or is `List<String>` acceptable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The easiest way to transform collection to array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293946/the-easiest-way-to-transform-collection-to-array)

Comment: Not a duplicate, it's not just transforming to array, it's transforming to array of a specific property (in this case - id)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public String[] getAllId() {
    return allPeople.stream().map(Person::getId).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Comment: Please note that this answer requires new methods and syntax introduced in Java 8.