# How to return a list of keys from a Hash Map?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm currently trying to make a program that conjugates verbs into Spanish.  I've created a Hash Table that contains a key and an instantiation of the object Verb.  The key is a string that has the infinitive form of the verb (for example, "hablar").  This is the code that I have so far for the hash map:

```
public class VerbHashMap {

    HashMap<String, Verb> verbHashMap;

    public VerbHashMap(){
        verbHashMap = new HashMap();
    }   
}
```

Each verb's key in the HashMap is based on the infinitive form of the verb.  For example, the string "hablar" is the key for a Spanish verb.  The class Verb has a method called getInfinitive() which returns a string that contains the infinitive form of the verb.

```
public boolean addVerb(Verb verb){
    if(verbHashMap.containsValue(verb.getInfinitive()){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        verbHashMap.put(verb.getInfinitive(), verb);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The question is what is the most efficient way to create a method that returns a list of all the verbs in the Hash Map in alphabetical order?  Should I have the method return an ArrayList which includes the keys of all the objects in the Hash Map?  Or is there a much more efficient way to go about this?

Comment: The way your `addVerb()` method checks for the existence of the value first, shouldn't the verb be the key?

Comment: This is probably the simplest question I've asked on SO, yet it has gotten me by far the most upvotes.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use the `keySet()` method to return a set with all the keys of a `Map`.

If you want to keep your Map ordered you can use a [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Comment: How can I get a List of keys and not a Set ? Because I need to access the individual keys after the Map is made.

Comment: @gonephishing You can use the set as a parameter for the constructor of an ArrayList for example..

Answer (score 106):

Using `map.keySet()`, you can get a set of keys. Then convert this set into `List` by:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
```

And then use `l.get(int)` method to access keys.

PS:- source- [Most concise way to convert a Set<String> to a List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319538/most-concise-way-to-convert-a-setstring-to-a-liststring)

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a chamo

Comment: this will raise a warning, no?

Answer (score 15):

```
List<String> yourList = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
```

This is will do just fine.

Answer (score 9):

```
map.keySet()
```

will return you all the keys. If you want the keys to be sorted, you might consider a TreeMap

Answer (score 9):

Since Java 8:

```
List<String> myList = map.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 for(int i=0;i<ytFiles.size();i++){

                    int key = ytFiles.keyAt(i);
                    Log.e("key", String.valueOf(key));
                    String format = ytFiles.get(key).getFormat().toString();
                    String url = ytFiles.get(key).getUrl();
                    Log.e("url",url);
                }
```

you can get key by method keyat and you have to pass the index then it will return key at that particular index. this loop will get all the key