# Get List<K> from HashMap<K, V> where V is instance of I

Tags: java, filter, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I am given `HashMap<K, V>`.
How to get list of all keys from it, where corresponding value is assignable from class I?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return a list of keys from a Hash Map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589744/how-to-return-a-list-of-keys-from-a-hash-map)

Comment: Seriously, you need to at least try something. HashMap is well documented, and you should know about loops.

Comment: I know, but aren't there more efficient ways to do this instead of iterating through HashMap?

Comment: Sure there are more concise ways, if you use Java-8 streams

Comment: Yes, I can use Java-8 streams. Can you tell me how to do it this way?

Comment: There is a big difference between "efficient" and "concise". Using a stream won't prevent iterating through the entries of the map.

Comment: @JBNizet ok, you are right

Answer (score 3):

Using Java 8 you can do

```
Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
List<K> list = map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() instanceof I)
        .map(e -> e.getKey())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

> where corresponding value is assignable from class I

Do you mean `value.getClass().isAssignableFrom(I.class)` ? If it's this the case:

```
Map<K, V> map = ...
List<K> keys = new ArrayList<K>();

for(K key : map.keySet()) {
    V value = map.get(key);

    if(value.getClass().isAssignableFrom(I.class)) {
        keys.add(key);
    }
}

//Now you have a list of keys associated to values that are assignable from I.class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the values of the `Map` using `Streams`.

```
Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
List<K> collect = map.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(entry -> I.class.isInstance(entry.getValue()))
                    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                    .collect(toList());
```